# Is "Everyone" or "Just me" the default option for a Windows Installer package?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

Microsoft has an article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/835460) which explains how to use the Orca database editor to remove the "Everyone" option and the "Just me" option from a Windows Installer package that you created by using Visual Studio .NET, but no where in that article do they explain what the default option is.  In other words, the application will either be installed for everyone or for just the user.  Does anyone know which it is?  Thanks.

Comment: Note to the close-voter: I don't consider this a question that belongs to SU. No normal user bothers with modifying MSI files usually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default for deployment projects (MSI files) for the InstallAllUsers property is "Just me".

*Abstract:*

> **InstallAllUsers Property**
>
> False — The application will only be
>   installed for the current user and
>   will not be visible to other users of
>   the computer (the default).
>
> True — The application will be
>   installed for all users.

Also the `InstallAllUsersVisible` property (available from VS.NET 2005 onwards), which seems to control whether the user option of choosing 'Just me' or 'Everyone' is visible at all. In other words, you don't need to fiddle with the Orca MSI database editor to show or hide this choice in your installer.

Comment: My apologies, Mr. Hollebrandse, for taking more than 3 years to acknowledge your answer.  Have a great week!