# c# installer application everyone

Tags: c#, windows-installer

For a c# installer project it is possible to remove the radio button "everyone" and "just me"
when installing. i always want this to be everyone. This article is the solution [Remove Everyone and Just Me](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/835460) and works perfectly.However After rebuild you have to do it again. which is alot of work. Is there an easier method?

thanks
Damo

Comment: Looks like this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2072490/279516

Comment: What tool are you using to author your MSI?

Comment: im using the orca application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Bob Horn. The specific solution is the following:

View->Editor->User Interface. Click on Installation folder. In the properties window there is a key InstallAllUsersVisible. Set it to false –