# MSI installer automatically starting after application already installed when using "Everyone" option?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I have an application that was created using Visual Studio which contains an installation project. When I run the MSI that is built, 3 Windows Services are created. Everything installs fine, the services are there and I can start them, when I choose the option to install for "Just Me".

When I choose the option to install for "Everyone", all users on this machine, the services are still installed fine and I can start them while I am logged in as the same user who installed them BUT when I log in as a different user and try starting the application using a shortcut, the installer starts up and tries to uninstall the services. Weird thing is that it only uninstalls 2 of the 3 services.

Again, if I install using "Just Me" I am having no issues at all, it seems to be linked to the "Everyone" option. I am not sure how to even begin looking into this as I am new to setup projects (this project was created by someone else) so any help would be great.

I'm thinking in one of the installation folders a file must be missing for the second user and that is why the installation folder opens up again?

Thanks for any help.

SOLUTION:
The issue was with the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property of the MSI because the shortcut that was installed for everyone was an Advertised Shortcut as far as I understand. There are a few ways to get around this using a post build event or using ORCA...we ended up using ORCA and adding the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS = 1 property to the MSI.

Solution and better explanation:

https://jcrawfor74.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/setup-app-config-during-msi-install-msi-re-installing/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/255905

Comment: This might help: [from another SO thread it looks like the Installer project itself contains a setting to 'Install for Everyone / Just Me'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072419/is-everyone-or-just-me-the-default-option-for-a-windows-installer-package). If you try using *that*, does it work correctly for all users?

Comment: [THis link might also help](http://darenatwork.blogspot.com/2013/01/everyone-vs-just-me-for-custom-actions.html)

Comment: @sab669 thanks! Your links helped push me in the right direction. Turns out it had to do with Advertised Shortcuts and the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property of the MSI. There are a few solutions for this but the one that is the simplest is to just modify the MSI file using ORCA which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the called `schema.msi` under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
```

This prototype is used in the consecutive generation of your deployment `msi` file. Then, you can use orca to add `DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1` to the Property table. So, from then on, all of your `msi` files will create the standard shortcut.